# Tild and minus operators in php

Tags: php, bitwise-operators, tilde, tilde-expansion

I have found this line of code:

```
for(;1<$argn/=++$x;);echo~$argn
```

As an answer on code golf. I googled about tild  symbol, and I found it's 2`complement.

So if it's like that why not simply use the `-` symbol. If they aren't equal symbols so what is the difference?

Comment: Write a script and compare `~$value` and `-$value`

Comment: `var_dump(~42, -42)` → `int(-43) int(-42)`